# How To Select Navigation Style in Tabbed Activity Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-tabbed-activity

I'm using Android Studio 3.3.1 on Mac.

I Cannot Find Navigation Style Option on Creating new Tabbed Activity Section.

I Used to select "Action Bar Tabs(with ViewPager)" but now i Can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

you need create a new project and select Add No Activity, when you are in the project open the java folder right click and select new activity and choose Tabbed Activity and you will can see the option Navigation Stile:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvMrb.png)